# How to get even numbers array to print first instead of odds?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this function where I've need to take out the evens and odds and put them into separate arrays but I need the evens array to print first rather than the odds.

```
var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

function divider(numbersArray) {
  var evensOdds = [[], []];
    for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
      evensOdds[i & 1].push(numbersArray[i]);
  }
  return evensOdds;
}
```

Comment: `return evensOdds.reverse();` ?

Comment: Intentional `evensOdds[i & 1]`? That looks like it separates them based on if the *index* is even or odd, but your question sounds like you want to separate them based on the *value*, not the index.

Comment: Using `i % 2` would be more clear that `i & 2` and could work for other dividers

Comment: @CRice No that wasn't intentional. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @alfasin That worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to split the number by their even and odd values, instead of using the index (`i`), determine the sub array to push into using the value -  `numbersArray[i] % 2`.

```js
var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

function divider(numbersArray) {
  var evensOdds = [[], []];
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    evensOdds[numbersArray[i] % 2].push(numbersArray[i]);
  }
  return evensOdds;
}

console.log(divider(numbersArray));
```

If you want to split them by even and odd indexes use `(i + 1) % 2` to determine the sub array to push into:

```js
var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

function divider(numbersArray) {
  var evensOdds = [[], []];
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    evensOdds[(i + 1) % 2].push(numbersArray[i]);
  }
  return evensOdds;
}

console.log(divider(numbersArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a `forEach` version of the accepted answer.

```js
    var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];
    var even_odd = [ [], [] ];

    numbersArray.forEach( e => even_odd[e%2].push(e) );

    console.log(even_odd);
```