# Filtering an array and converting it to a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I saw this interesting post yesterday, and thought it'd be important to know how to create a 2D array from sorting the given argument:
[How to get even numbers array to print first instead of odds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290845/how-to-get-even-numbers-array-to-print-first-instead-of-odds)

Below is the code snippet from Ori Drori.

I was curious to know what line of code, and which expression sorts the data and creates 2D array. I assume it's something to do with [numbersArray[i] % 2], but isn't the remainder operator returns the remainder left over?

Also it's a bit confusing as it just set one bracket for an array and use push() to make 2 different arrays.

Any reference that'd help me to understand this will also be much appreciated- thanks!

```js
var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

function divider(numbersArray) {
  var evensOdds = [[], []];
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    evensOdds[numbersArray[i] % 2].push(numbersArray[i]);
  }
  return evensOdds;
}

console.log(divider(numbersArray));
```

Comment: The `var evensOdds = [[], []];`  initializes a 2d array. The expression `numbersArray[i] % 2` result is always 0 or 1, and I use it to decide to which sub array to push the number.

Comment: The output data is split into two arrays but both definitely are not sorted.

Comment: Do not think about it as 2D.  Think about it as an array that consists of two arrays.

Comment: @OriDrori thanks so much ori! couldn't figure out how to reach you(don't have enough credits ha) so had to write a new question

Comment: @bom - welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evensOdds` has 2 array elements. `evensOdds[0]` represents first array, which will hold even nums. `evensOdds[1]` is second element and will hold odd numbers.

When you `% 2` an even number, it will result in `0` and `1` for odd number. So when iterating through the array, you `% 2`, which will return `0` or `1` which enables you to access the first or second array in your `evensOdds` array and insert it.

The resulting arrays are not sorted but does represent the split between even and odd numbers. To have a sorted results, you will need the following:

```js
var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

function divider(numbersArray) {
  var evensOdds = [[], []];
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    evensOdds[numbersArray[i] % 2].push(numbersArray[i]);
  }
  return evensOdds.map(array=> array.sort((a,b)=>a-b));
}

console.log(divider(numbersArray));
```

Comment: now it all makes sense thanks so much! so the first bracket indicates the index number of the evensOdds. you're a life saverrr

Answer (score 1):

In the shared code the `evensOdds[numbersArray[i] % 2]` line is the part that filter the numbers and inserts them in the respective `array`, using the indexes `0` and `1` returned from the `numbersArray[i] % 2` expression:

If it returns `0` so it's an `even` number and it will be pushed in the first `array` otherwise if it returns `1` it's an `odd` number and will be pushed in the second array.

**Another alternative:**

Well you can simply use [**`Array.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter both `evens` and `odds` arrays:

**Demo:**

```js
var numbersArray = [1, 2, 34, 54, 55, 34, 32, 11, 19, 17, 54, 66, 13];

var evens = numbersArray.filter(function(el) {
  return el % 2 == 0;
});

var odds = numbersArray.filter(function(el) {
  return el % 2 == 1;
});

console.log(evens);

console.log(odds);
```

Comment: thank you so much!! yea i didn't realize the first bracket's a convertible one that gives either index0 or 1.